# Retrieve post array values

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a form that sends all the data with jQuery `.serialize()` In the form are four `arrays qty[], etc` it send the form data to a sendMail page and I want to get the posted data back out of the arrays.

I have tried:

```
$qty = $_POST['qty[]'];
foreach($qty as $value)
{
  $qtyOut = $value . "<br>";
}
```

And tried this:

```
for($q=0;$q<=$qty;$q++)
{
 $qtyOut = $q . "<br>";
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Try with `$qty = $_POST['qty'];`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have `[]` within your `$_POST` variable - these aren't required. You should use:

`$qty = $_POST['qty'];`

Your code would then be:

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];

foreach($qty as $value) {

   $qtyOut = $value . "<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 8):

php automatically detects **$_POST** and **$_GET**-arrays so you can juse:

```
<form method="post">
    <input value="user1"  name="qty[]" type="checkbox">
    <input value="user2"  name="qty[]" type="checkbox">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
```

and **$qty** will by a php-Array. Now you can access it by:

```
if (is_array($qty))
{
  for ($i=0;$i<size($qty);$i++)
  {
    print ($qty[$i]);
  }
}
?>
```

if you are not sure about the format of the received data structure you can use:

```
print_r($_POST['qty']);
```

or even

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to see how it is stored.

Comment: Exactly. One worth noting: don't forget the [ ] in the name of your input in HTML. I forgot this one and I've wasted hours of my life.

Comment: Your answer is perfect to multi arrays. For example, I'll post names and ages, with that for I can get both values at once.

Comment: To add onto this, by setting actual values between the brackets instead of leaving them empty and by parsing the the returned array by this **foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)** foreach loop you can preserve the id's. Useful when working with multiple pages

Answer (score 1):

My version of PHP 4.4.4 throws an error:
***Fatal error: Call to undefined function: size()***

I changed **size** to **count** and then the routine ran correctly.

```
<?php
$qty = $_POST['qty'];

if (is_array($qty)) {
   for ($i=0;$i<count($qty);$i++)
   {
       print ($qty[$i]);
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using filter_input()  with filters FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS and FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY as shown

```
$qty=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qty',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

then you can iterate through it nicely as

```
foreach($qty as $key=>$value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP handles nested arrays nicely

try:

```
foreach($_POST['qty'] as $qty){
   echo $qty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer foreach insted of for, because you do not need to heandle the size.

```
if( isset( $_POST['qty'] ) )
{
    $qty = $_POST ['qty'] ;
    if( is_array( $qty ) )
    {
        foreach ( $qty as $key => $value ) 
        {
            print( $value );
        }
    }
}
```