# Insert data from a dynamic form into database

Tags: php, html, database

I'm learning to program with Php. 
I have an index page html with a dynamic form linked to a connection.php page in which I have done the connection to the database and also where I create a query to insert data into database ( Is it right how I'm proceeding? ).

I want to show you the code:

**index.html**

```
<body>    
        <form action="connection.php" class="register" method="POST">
            <h1>Conferenza</h1>
            <fieldset class="row1">
                <legend>Informazioni Richiedente Prenotazione</legend>
                <p>
                    <label>Nome
                    </label>
                    <input name="nome" type="text" required="required"/>
                    <label>Cognome
                    </label>
                    <input name="cognome" type="text" required="required"/>
                    <label>Data Videoconferenza 
                    </label>
                    <select class="date" name="day">
                        <option value="1">01
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">02
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">03
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">04
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">05
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">06
                        </option>
                        <option value="7">07
                        </option>
                        <option value="8">08
                        </option>
                        <option value="9">09
                        </option>
                        <option value="10">10
                        </option>
                        <option value="11">11
                        </option>
                        <option value="12">12
                        </option>
                        <option value="13">13
                        </option>
                        <option value="14">14
                        </option>
                        <option value="15">15
                        </option>
                        <option value="16">16
                        </option>
                        <option value="17">17
                        </option>
                        <option value="18">18
                        </option>
                        <option value="19">19
                        </option>
                        <option value="20">20
                        </option>
                        <option value="21">21
                        </option>
                        <option value="22">22
                        </option>
                        <option value="23">23
                        </option>
                        <option value="24">24
                        </option>
                        <option value="25">25
                        </option>
                        <option value="26">26
                        </option>
                        <option value="27">27
                        </option>
                        <option value="28">28
                        </option>
                        <option value="29">29
                        </option>
                        <option value="30">30
                        </option>
                        <option value="31">31
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="month">
                        <option value="1">January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">June
                        </option>
                        <option value="7">July
                        </option>
                        <option value="8">August
                        </option>
                        <option value="9">September
                        </option>
                        <option value="10">October
                        </option>
                        <option value="11">November
                        </option>
                        <option value="12">December
                        </option>
                    </select>   
                    <br>    
                    <br>            
                    <label>Email 
                    </label>
                   <input name="email" type="text" required="required"/>
                   <label>Stanza
                    </label>
                    <select name="stanza">
                        <option value="1">Stanza 1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">Stanza 2
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Oggetto Prenotazione
                    </label>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="oggetto" form="usrform" placeholder="Inserire Oggetto Conferenza"></textarea>
                    <br>

                </p>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Personale </legend>
                <p> 
                    <input type="button" value="Add Passenger" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Passenger" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
                    <p>(All acions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
                </p>
               <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <p>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Nome</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="nome_p[]">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label for="Cognome">Cognome</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="cognome_p[]">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label for="Email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="email_p[]">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label for="Tipologia">Tipologia</label>
                            <select id="BX_birth" name="tipologia[]" required="required">
                                <option>Interno</option>
                                <option>esterno</option>

                            </select>
                         </td>
                            </p>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>

            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />


            <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>

    </body>
```

process.php

```
<body>    
        <form action="connection.php" class="register">
            <h1>YouAreBUS Ticket Reservation</h1>
            <?php if(isset($_POST)==true && empty($_POST)==false): 
                $chkbox = $_POST['chk'];
                $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                $day = $_POST['day'];
                $month = $_POST['month'];
                $mob = $_POST['mob'];
                $type = $_POST['type'];
                $oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
                $to=$_POST['to'];
                $stanza=$_POST['stanza'];
                $nome_int=$_POST['nome_int'];
                $cognome_int=$_POST['cognome_int'];         
                $email_int=$_POST['email_int'];
                $tipologia=$_POST['tipologia'];                 
            ?>
            <fieldset class="row1">
                <legend>Informazioni Richiedente Prenotazione</legend>
                <p>
                    <label>Nome 
                    </label>
                    <input name="nome" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $nome ?>"/>
                    <label>Data Videoconferenza
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="small" value="<?php echo $day ?>"/>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="small" value="<?php echo $month ?>"/>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="small" value="2013"/>
                    <label>Email 
                    </label>
                    <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $email ?>"/>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Oggetto Prenotazione
                    </label>
                    <input name="oggetto" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $oggetto ?>"/>

                    <label>Stanza
                    </label>
                    <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $stanza ?>"/>

                </p>


                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Personale
                </legend>               
                <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($nome_p as $a => $b){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <p>
                                <td >
                                    <?php echo $a+1; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label>Nome</label>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="nome_p[$a]" value="<?php echo $nome_p[$a]; ?>">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="Cognome"></label>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="small"  name="cognome_p[]" value="<?php echo $cognome_p[$a]; ?>">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="Email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="email_p[]" value="<?php echo $BX_gender[$a]; ?>">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="BX_birth">Berth Pre</label>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="tipologia[]" value="<?php echo $tipologia[$a]; ?>">
                                </td>
                            </p>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>

          <fieldset class="row5">
                <legend>Terms and Mailing</legend>
                <p>
                    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Make Payment &raquo;" />
                    <a class="submit" href="index.html" type="button"> Back To Demo <a/>
                </p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
        <?php else: ?>
        <fieldset class="row1">
            <legend>Sorry</legend>
             <p>Some things went wrong please try again.</p>
        </fieldset>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

And also

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456789";
$dbname = "Project";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $stanza = $_POST['stanza'];
    $oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
    $nome_p = $_POST['nome_p[]'];
    $cognome_p = $_POST['cognome_p[]'];
    $email_p = $_POST['email_p[]'];
    $tipologia = $_POST['tipologia[]'];


$query = "INSERT into Prenotazione (nome,cognome,day,month,email,stanza,oggetto) values('$nome','$cognome','$day','$month','$email','$stanza','$oggetto')";
$query1 = "INSERT into Personale (nome_p,cognome_p,email_p,tipologia,email,oggetto) values('$nome_p','$cognome_p','$email_p','$tipologia','$email','$oggetto')";

}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $query1)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query1 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and scripts.js

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 5){                           // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 5.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                         // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is about the insert into database, because the query that I have write shouldn't be right.
My database have 2 tables:

Prenotazione:
    nome
    cognome
    date
    email
    stanza
    oggetto

Personale:
    nome_p
    cognome_p
    email_p
    tipologia
    email_richiedente 
    oggetto_richiedente

In your opinion who can I write the query to insert data from the dynamic form?

thanks a lot for your help!

UPDATE. This is my page when I click the button Confirm.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPM8N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Code seems pretty right to me except for one thing. The insert SQL Query. Form values in PHP can be accessed through $_GET[] or $_POST[] array and the 'name' attribute as the key. Since you are using POST method in your form, use $_POST[]. I'll give you an example here to give you an idea:

HTML:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"/><label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="age"/><label>Age</label>
    <input type="text name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
/*Now here is the part where you should change your code based on this example
  As you notice we used $_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'] and $_POST['age'] because as I have said we get their values by their name attribute. 
  PHP works this way.
*/

/* Use isset to check if the form datas are there. Often without the isset, you'll get an undefined index error. */
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /* Declare POST form datas into variables just for a better code format */
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(name, age) VALUES($name, $age)";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Do not forgot to validate first each value from user, before run-it against database, as not doing that can lead to security issues.

Comment: Oh yes. Also do not forget to sanitize form datas.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I realized that it did not work as I had written it (in fact it did nothing but insert what I had written, not the actual data). I modified the code as you told me, only this time it does not insert anything (to be precise in the Prenotazione table gives me error, instead in the Personale table instead I enter the data but all null, empty)

Comment: Try running the SQL query in PHPMyAdmin or any database and seek for the error. Maybe a wrong spelling of column or table is causing it.

Comment: @GioRodriguez You're so kind to help me! I tried to run SQL queries directly on phpmyadmin like this: $query = "INSERT into Prenotazione (nome,cognome,data,email,stanza,oggetto) values('$nome','$cognome','$data','$email','$stanza','$oggetto')";
and Enter these values $nome, $cognome etc ..into table
But when I try to fill out the form on my web page and click on the "confirm" button, I'm sent back to a blank page without anything being added to the database

Comment: I noticed one of your input tags have a name attribute of 'day'. I assume you mistyped it as data?

Comment: Yes I change "data" in day(int) e month(varchar). 
At this point I receive a page with: 

Error:
Error:

and not a white page

Answer (score 0):

Actually you must read [Retrieve post array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750478/retrieve-post-array-values) This is because  you have in your index.html some input tags that are not "correctly" named. This can lead to confusion. Names like "arr[]" in input tags are used most of the time to organize the arrays on post and allow them to be accessed on php side like $_POST['arr']. I am not sure what $_POST['arr[]'] will return to you, but it seem not to be something useful. In the example you sent, it seem you need to iterate trough each $_POST sub-arrays in order to build your sql for insert. For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <?php
    print_r($_POST);

   ?>
    <form name="form1" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name1" />
    <input type="text" name="name2" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <form name="form2" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name[1]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[2]" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form name="form3" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

will lead to the following output, if you use a and b as form input values

```
Array ( [name1] => a [name2] => b )
```

for first form,

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [1] => a [2] => b ) )
```

for second form and

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b ) )
```

for third form ( the "name" array is auto-indexed)

Hope it helps